# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания

Tags: орфография

В случае несоответствия присланных материалов заявленным требованиям к оформлению по решению оргкомитета Конкурса работы могут быть отклонены.

Answer (score 2):

***В случае несоответствия присланных материалов заявленным требованиям к оформлению***,  по решению оргкомитета Конкурса работы могут быть отклонены.

В данном случае в начале предложения находятся **два распространенных обстоятельственных оборота**, при этом один их них желательно обособить для удобства прочтения текста (в общем случае обособление таких оборотов **факультативно)**.

Первый оборот имеет условное значение и является **аналогом условного придаточного предложения** (по смыслу и по интонации).

Answer (score 0):

У Вас правильно написано. Знаков препинания не требуется. Другое дело, что в предложение надо вчитываться, чтобы понять смысл.

Предлагаю переделать его так:

*Если присланные материалы не будут соответствовать заявленным требованиям к оформлению, то оргкомитет Конкурса может принять решение об их отклонении.*